How to Invoice Status for a Quick Books Invoice QuickBooks PHP SDK
Am trying to get the status of an invoice queried using
QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService::Query("Select * Invoice");

The invoices are returned successfully, but how can I get their status.
It seems like there is no
status

property on the invoice object. Tried looking at it but its not there.

Go to the bank register the first check that is marked "C" or not if mark "C" then run the reconciliation process.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
